# Determine the processor capabilities at run time

Tags: assembly, mobile, windows-mobile, parallel-processing, arm

I have written some Assembly code for parallel processing using ARM Wireless MMX technology and it runs fine on devices with processors (Intel XScale processors) that support MMX. But on devices with processors (Qualcomm processors) that do not support MMX, the code crashes.

Is there any way to determine the processor capabilities at run time and run my code only if the processor supports Wireless MMX?

Ideally I'm looking for Windows CE APIs to determine the processor extensions. I have tried the standard APIs like GetSystemInfo() that tell us the processor type but they doesn't give the details about processor extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If available I'd recommend calling [`IsProcessorFeaturePresent(PF_ARM_INTEL_WMMX)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886726.aspx).